# Create transition inside a `minted` environment

Tags: beamer, minted

I'm using *minted* to highlight some code. With the `escapeinside` I can add custom LaTeX code. For example:

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{py}
def f(x):
    y = x|\colorbox{green}{**}|2
    return y
\end{minted}
```

now I'd like to add an efect to the beamer frame:

- show the code without the colorbox
- advance the presentation
- show the code with the colorbox

that would be a typical beamer transition modifier like `<2->`.

Trying to merge both features I tried:

```
...
y = x|<2->\colorbox{green}{**}|2
...
```

but it didn't worked: the `<2->` was rendered as it.

**Is it possible to add some effects like `<2->` or `\pause` or equivalent inside a *minted* environment?**

Comment: You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small document that shows your problem. Just edit your question and add the code.

Comment: Does the `\colorbox{green}` work? If yes you could simply use a custom colour and redefine it from white to green between the overlay.

Comment: @samcarter, the `\colorbox{}` works. The text is rendered highlighted and the `**` is enclosed in a green box.

Comment: Can you make your code compilabale? This would be a great staring point.

Comment: I filled a [request in GH](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/155), check the suggestion there.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to bring overlays into `minted`, maybe redefining the colour between the overlays could be enough:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{1,1,1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1-2>
    \only<2>{\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0,1,0}}
    \colorbox{mycolor}{test}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the `\only<2>{}` trick worked for defined a color, any recommendation for conditionally define a command?

Comment: @mmoya my recommendation is: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353740/create-transition-inside-a-minted-environment/353783?noredirect=1#comment869807_353740